# All floats feedback a rounded down integer

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, c++, float

So I am very confused at the results I am getting.
It seems that floats aren't working properly, and I don't understand why.

I was trying to read a temp sensor and convert the reading to celsius. However, when I tried to divide the value (an int between 145-165) by 1024, and multiply by 5 I would get back a float value of 0.00 
Here's the code I was using

```
    void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);

}

void loop() {
  int sensorVal = analogRead(A0);
    Serial.print("Sensor Value: ");
    Serial.println(sensorVal);

  float voltage = ((sensorVal/1024) * 5);
    Serial.print("Voltage Value: ");
    Serial.println(voltage);

}
```

This would only return values of 0.00 for voltage, even though the sensor itself is working fine, returning varying values between 146 and 165 based on how much heat I apply.
This didn't make any sense, so I tried it with some other values, eg.

```
Serial.print(float (10 / 6));
```

and

```
Serial.print(float (5 / 2));
```

which should have returned 1.67 and 2.50 respectively, but instead returned 1.00 and 2.00

I think it might be a settings thing, where all floats round down to an int, but that seems really weird.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Hint: Try `float voltage = ((sensorVal/1024.0) * 5.0);`

Comment: FYI, your intermediate results are truncated, not rounded. ( `0/11` will yield 1, since the answer is ≈1.81, and it simply strips away the decimal part. By comparison, `round(20.0/11.0)` will give you a value of 2.0, since 1.8181 rounded rounds up to 2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing integer arithmetic. Try adding .0 to the end of your values where you need the floating point results.

For example...

```
  float voltage = ((sensorVal/1024.0) * 5.0);
```

Remember the results of analog read is an integer. So the conversion to a float in you original code only happens when the "=" is being "executed". Another possibility is to cast it to a float straight away.

```
  float voltage = ((((float)sensorVal)/1024.0) * 5.0);
```

Or more simply

```
  float voltage = ((float)sensorVal)/1024.0 * 5.0;
```

Comment: This helped a lot. I realized that I should have also initialized my sensorVal as a float

Answer (score 4):

You already got a couple of perfectly good answer. I will nevertheless
suggest a slightly different idiom:

```
float voltage = sensorVal * (5.0 / 1024);
```

or, maybe better:

```
const float V_REF = 5.0;  // at the top of the sketch

float voltage = sensorVal * (V_REF / 1024);
```

The reason this is slightly better than the other options is because
division – even integer division – is a very expensive
operation on the smaller Arduinos. By writing the conversion as in the
lines above, the ratio `V_REF / 1024` becomes a compile-time constant,
which is evaluated by the compiler at build time. Then, only the much
cheaper multiplication needs to be done by the Arduino itself, at run
time. Not a big deal if you are not time constrained, but it's a
low-hanging fruit in terms of optimization.

You may write `1024.0` instead of `1024` if it feels safer. I tend to
keep the `.0` for the voltage only, because 1024 is an integer, whereas
the “5” in “5 volts” is conceptually a real number (it's an
*analog* voltage, and not even exactly 5 V if you bother to measure
it). But this is just a personal preference at the end.

Comment: Good point on avoiding runtime division. (voted)

Comment: I must admit @edgar_bonet, I found what you said very hard to believe - after all one of the things that an optimising compilers should check for is "constant arithmetic" and "work it out for you" and just apply the result. That is, `x / 1023.0 * 5.0` should be optimised as `(X / 204.6)` . Since I didn't believe you (sorry about that), I tried a simple program and was **stunned** to see that it actually executes the division of the constants in the generated assembler - unless you put that part of the expression in parenthesis.

Comment: What was also of interest was that in my first version I simply put `int reading = analogRead(A0);  float result = reading / 1023.0 * 5.0;` in my `setup()` function with nothing else. Long story short, the compiler optimised the whole block of code out of the generated assembler (because I wasn't doing anything with the result). It wasn't until I put in `Serial.println(result);` that the calculation was emitted by the compiler.
I was going to down vote you ('cos I thought you were wrong), but after checking and found you were right - you get an upvote from me to.

Comment: @GMc: The compiler cannot optimize `x / 1023.0 * 5.0` into `x * (5.0 / 1023.0)` because the two expressions, although equivalent in the realm of _real_ numbers, are not equivalent for _floating point_ numbers. The compiler is not allowed to perform an optimization that can possibly modify the result of a computation. That is, unless you give it an option like `-funsafe-math-optimizations`, which is off by default.

Comment: @edgar_bonet thanks for the insights and the great addition to the answer I will definitely explore this further.

Answer (score 2):

GMc explained what to do, but didn't explain in detail why your code fails to give floating point results.

Most languages evaluate expressions using order of operations. C and C++ are no exception to this.

In C/C++, while the expression is being evaluated, the compiler also decides what data types to use for each part. integer-integer expressions are evaluated using integer math. If either of the parts of an expression is a larger/floating point type, both values are "promoted" to the larger/more complex type before evaluating the expression.

in your code

```
float voltage = ((sensorVal/1024) * 5);
```

The `sensorVal/1024` bit is evaluate first. Since both `sensorVal` and `1024` are integers, the compiler uses integer math. That yields an int result, and so any fractional part is truncated and lost.

It then evaluates `result*5` (where `result` is the result of the first part, `sensorVal/1024`, which is an integer.) Both of those parts are integers, so the result of that expression is an int.

Finally, you ask the compiler to store the result into a float, `voltage`. The compiler then promotes the integer result of the whole expression to a float, but you've lost any floating point part of your calculations.

By rewriting your line as

```
float voltage = ((sensorVal/1024.0) * 5.0);
```

The compiler does what you want. The `sensorVal/1024.0` bit is now integer-float math, so the compiler "promotes" `sensorVal` to a float and then does float-float math. The second part is now float-float, so the result is also floating point.

```
float voltage = ((sensorVal/1024.0) * 5);
```

Would also work in this case (where `5` is an integer constant.) That works because `float_result*5` is float-integer math, and the compiler will promote `5` to a floating point value and do float-float math. to get the final result. However, it's safer to use all floating point constants so you don't accidentally do part of your calculations using integer math and truncate that part before converting to floating point.

As you say, making `sensorVal` a float also would be a good idea. (Again, to avoid accidentally doing integer math on part of your expression and getting wrong results in the process. In this case making `sensorVal` a float isn't needed, but with a different expression you might wind up with integer math for part of the calculation.)